# How to send an object from a server to windows phone and back?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a server and a client in C#, as a desktop application, and I'm sending objects between them by using a `BinaryFormatter`. This works fine, but now I want to send objects to a windows phone device and back. I've read about `DataContractSerializer` on windows phone, but i'm not sure what to use on the server side. What can I use that will work both ways on both the server and the client.

I want to serialize the object to a byte array and send it over a socket. As a reference, i'm using this: [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use XmlSerializer or some of the JSON serializers (i.e JSON.net).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Will this work for any object with any type of variable? Also, i have the object i want to serialize in a Portable Class Library, how can i make it serializable ( i just noticed now, that it't not excepting `[Serializable]`).

Comment: well, there are couple of quirks but it is easy to make it work. you need the Serializable attribute, a parameterless constructor and all properties must have public getter and setter.

Comment: Thanks. What about if i dont want to use xml serialization, what other options are there? Like if my object has private variables...

Comment: if you want to have private vars you need to roll your own serialization/dreserialization mechanism.